# Can't stop a windows service,

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to make a windows service disabled or start automatically. When I run this code it returns 2 and nothing changes about the service:

```
using (var m = new ManagementObject(string.Format("Win32_Service.Name=\"{0}\"", servName))) {
  var a = m.InvokeMethod("ChangeStartMode", new object[] { "Disabled" }); // or "Automatic"; 
}
```

Why and how fix it? And "a" is equal to "2", what does "2" mean?

Answer (score 0):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384896(v=vs.85).aspx

Return code 2 means Access Denied:

> The user did not have the necessary access.

Comment: and how to fix that?

Comment: Try right-click the exe file, go to Properties > Compatibility and check the 'Run this program as admin' box

Comment: I need to run it from Visual Studio. How?

Comment: Run Visual Studio as admin.